# perl parsing and assigning multiple values to hash key using array

Tags: arrays, perl, file-io, hash

I have  files that I'm trying to parse and build a hash and lookup from a third file. File format :

File 1:

```
ID2
ID4
```

File 2:

```
x1 y1 z1 ID1
x2 y2 z2 ID2
x3 y3 z3 ID2
x4 y4 z4 ID4
```

File 3:

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
```

What I'm trying to do :

For all those IDs in File1, look up x and y coordinate using ID field in File2 , and see if 'a' in File3 lies between x and y.

What I have thought so far :

1. Take file 2; parse it into a hash using ID as the key
2. Take file 1; if ID exists in file 2; open file 3 and check coordinates ranges for 'a'
   and print it

How far have I executed? 
Not too far. I am trying to read File 2 and parse all element in a hash, but I'm stuck:

```
while (<FILE>){
    chomp $_;
    my $line = $_;
    my @arr  = split ("\t", $line);
    my $id = $arr[3];

    if (exists ($hash{$id})) {
        my $x = $arr[0];
        my $y  = $arr[1];
        my $z   = $arr[2];
        push @{$hash{$id}{'x'}, $x;
        push @{$hash{$id}{'y'}, $y;
        push @{$hash{$id}{'y'}, $y;
    } else {
        $hash{'id'} = $id;
        $hash{$id}{'x'} = $arr[0];   
        $hash{$id}{'y'} = $arr[1];
        $hash{$id}{'z'} = $arr[2];
    }
}
print Dumper %hash;
close FILE;
```

But of course, I'm doing something wrong here

Comment: I spy with my little eye (1) A syntax error `@{$hash{$id}{'y'}` ← where does the dereference stop? (2) An `y` and `$y` where there should be `z`/`$z` (3) In the `else`, you define `$hash{id}` to be a string, but then use it as a hashref which holds scalars. But in the `if`, you treat them as hashrefs of arrayrefs (I guess). Maybe you should show us the *expected* data structure.

Comment: Sorry this was just the initial musings. I'm not real familiar when it comes to hashes of arrays, so forgive the syntax errors.

Expected data structure should be something like below, where it takes into account multiple values of x , y and z for the same ID. 

$VAR58477 = 'ID2';
$VAR58478 = {
              'x' => [
                          'x2','x3,
                        ],
              'y' => [
                         'y2','y3'
                       ],
              'z' => [
                           'z2','z3'
                         ]
            };

Answer (score 1):

This is how to read your `file2` into a hash. Note that I think it may be easier to use three-element arrays to hold the x, y and z values rather than a hash.

I would show more but I'm very unclear about how your `file3` works, and how it is related to `file1`. Do you want to process all values in `file1` and find, for each of them, which values in `file3` are between the corresponding limits?

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Data::Dump;

open my $fh, '<', 'file2.txt';

my %data;

while (<$fh>){
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\t/;
    my $id = pop @fields;
    for ('x' .. 'z') {
      push @{$data{$id}{$_}}, shift @fields;
    }
}

dd \%data;
```

**output**

```
{
  ID1 => { x => ["x1"], y => ["y1"], z => ["z1"] },
  ID2 => { x => ["x2", "x3"], y => ["y2", "y3"], z => ["z2", "z3"] },
  ID4 => { x => ["x4"], y => ["y4"], z => ["z4"] },
}
```

---

**Update**

Although the storage format from the above code is what I think you intended I don't think it's very workable. I think it would be easier for you to code the rest of the program if you use this

```
while (<$fh>){
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\t/;
    my $id = pop @fields;
    push @{$data{$id}}, \@fields;
}
```

resulting in this

```
{
  ID1 => [["x1", "y1", "z1"]],
  ID2 => [["x2", "y2", "z2"], ["x3", "y3", "z3"]],
  ID4 => [["x4", "y4", "z4"]],
}
```

or even this

```
while (<$fh>){
    chomp;
    my @fields = split /\t/;
    my $id = pop @fields;
    my %item;
    @item{qw/ x y z /} = @fields;
    push @{$data{$id}}, \%item;
}
```

which results in this data

```
{
  ID1 => [{ x => "x1", y => "y1", z => "z1" }],
  ID2 => [
           { x => "x2", y => "y2", z => "z2" },
           { x => "x3", y => "y3", z => "z3" },
         ],
  ID4 => [{ x => "x4", y => "y4", z => "z4" }],
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that one of the `ID2`'s is going to be lost from `file2` here.

Comment: @chrsblck: True, I didn't spot that.

Comment: Yes I agree with chrsblck, thats one of the biggest challenges here is how to retain multiple x,y,z for same ID (eg ID2) which is why i thought of using array

Comment: @user2199881: I have changed it to do what I think your original code intended, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: Also, as far as File3 , I added another column. Here I need to check if a is same as 'x' and if 'b' is between 'y' and 'z' (both are numbers).

In a way I'm trying to join File 1 and File 2 using ID and then looking up file 3 entries

Comment: @user2199881: OK "joining" `file1` and `file2` on ID gives you a subset of the xyz values in `file2`. So given a set of xyz values and a set of ab values, and a rule to apply between them, what output do you want?

Comment: Output can just be x,y,z,ID as well as a,b. Also, I dont know what you are doing in this step :
push @{$data{$id}}, \@fields;

How is it assigning multiple x,y,z values for ID?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach your task this way:

1. load file 1 into memory and keep it as a filter of IDs
2. tie file 3 or load it into memory and otherwise keep it around to index into
3. process file 2 as a stream of requests.

Thus:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
use common::sense;
use Tie::File;
use autodie;

tie my @table, 'Tie::File', 'f3' or die $!;

my %filter;
open my $f, '<', 'f1';
while (<$f>) {
  chomp;
  $filter{$_}++
}
close $f;

while (<>) {
  next unless /^x(\d+) y(\d+) z\d+ (ID\d+)$/;
  next unless exists $filter{$3};
  say((split ' ', $table[$2])[$1])
}

untie @table;
```

Usage:

```
$ ./example
x1 y1 z2 ID2
b2
x0 y0 z5 ID2
a1

$ ./example file2
<three blank lines, because your examples are 1-indexed>
```